# Only number for a decimal attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Information < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :credit, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.0 }, :allow_blank => true

end
```

In the view:

```
<%= f.text_field :credit, placeholder: 'Money...' %>
```

The problem is that if I enter "abc100" it adds to my credit 0.0 and it returns a successful message, but I want to show the user that what he wrote is wrong...I thought to use a regex in the Information model, but the attribute type is an integer...so what's up?

Comment: What you have should be able to provide a "not a number" error for the value "abc100".  If you switch to a simple validation like `validates_presence_of :credit` does that show an error when the value is blank?  You're not accidentally passing `validate: false` in the save code in your controller are you?  Can you post your controller's create/update method?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the HTML5 `number` input type, there's even a Rails helper for it:

```
f.number_field :credit, placeholder: 'Money...'
```

Options for `number_field` like `min` and `max` are described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-number_field_tag).

Comment: just done, but in firefox it doesn't work, second I need to input also decimal numbers not only integer

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery Plugin

[jQuery Plugin – Numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use one of the newer HTML5 input types, as described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-number_field_tag) and [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html)

Since those are newer HTML5 features, you are absolutely right and they may not work in all browsers (see [CanIUse Page on the subject](http://caniuse.com/input-number)). So I would use client-side form validations, for example described [in this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations)

Finally, **regardless** of how you build your HTML/front-end code, your model should be resilient to browsers and requests that may not respect it. Use **numericality** model validations for that: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality